# Why are my colliders offset on my isometric map?

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection, isometric

I'm building an isometric environment in Unity and having some trouble with my colliders aligning with what shows in the scene editor to the reality in gameplay.

There is nothing in the collider component to indicate that it should have any offset, or that there is anything at play other than the default settings.  This goes for all types of 2D colliders I should add.  I did try a 3D collider just out of curiosity, and nothing happens at all.  This has been my experience with multiple objects, not only the one I've highlighted in the picture below.

I'm using the Adventure Creator add-on if that makes any difference.

[image: Scene Editor position vs Gameplay reality]

Comment: I'm not sure what the red circle in the second screenshot is supposed to tell me.

Comment: Also, is [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/templates/systems/adventure-creator-11896) the "adventure creator" asset you are referring to?

Comment: The red circle is what I'm actually colliding with.  Yes that's the asset.